# MySQL SELECT to return rows with change in field value

Tags: mysql, sql, select

This is the table1 structure:

```
ID_Num | id_2 | field1
12-001 | 3    | ABCD
12-001 | 3    | ABCD
12-001 | 3    | ABCD
12-001 | 1    | ABCD
12-001 | 1    | ABCD
12-002 | 3    | ABCD
12-002 | 3    | ABCD
12-002 | 3    | ABCD
12-002 | 3    | ABCD
12-002 | 3    | ABCD
12-003 | 2    | ABCD
12-003 | 2    | ABCD
12-003 | 3    | ABCD
12-003 | 3    | ABCD
12-003 | 3    | ABCD
```

Now I want to select all ID_Num that has a change in field id_2
It should return 12-001 because of change from 3 to 1
and 12-003 because of change from 2 to 3

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  ID_NUM
FROM    tableNAME
GROUP   BY ID_NUM
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT id_2) > 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2abd4/2)

Comment: @paynet: Careful about relying on [MySQL's GROUP BY/hidden column functionality](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html)

Comment: @OMGPonies: This query doesn't though, does it?

Answer (score 0):

I realize that `count(distinct)` requires more processing than the following:

```
select id_num
from tablename
group by id_num
having min(id_2) <> max(id_2)
```

This does not treat NULL as a separate value, but there are no NULLs in the question.